# Возможно ли сочетать при описании мальчика слово общего рода с глаголом женского рода?

Tags: грамматика, существительные, род

Можно ли сказать о мальчике "неряха обронила вещи" или "круглая неряха"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кроме имен существительных мужского, женского и среднего рода, выделяется группа существительных общего рода (*невидимка, тихоня, сирота, задира, умница*...).
**Вне контекста их род не определяется.** В зависимости от конкретных обстоятельств они могут выступать то как существительные мужского рода, то как существительные женского рода.

Конкретное значение пола проявляется у существительных общего рода только в предложении. Для реализации значения мужского и женского пола используются синтаксические средства:

1. Местоимения (он, она, тот, та, этот, эта, моей, моим). ***Этот*** сладкоежка. **Эта** сладкоежка.
2. Слова женщина, мужчина, девочка, мальчик и др. ***Мальчик*** грязнуля. **Девочка** грязнуля.
3. Имена собственные. ***Миша*** лежебока. **Маша** лежебока.
4. Глаголы в форме прошедшего времени. ***Был*** чистюлей. **Была** чистюлей.
5. Прилагательные. *Женя — **круглый** сирота. Женя — **круглая** сирота.*

Итак, **если пол известен**, то согласование по роду **обязательно**. О мальчике: неряха обронил вещи; большой неряха, страшный неряха.
Прилагательное *круглый* (в значении полный, совершенный) применяется обычно при описании глупости, невежества: круглый болван, круглый дурак, круглый невежда. ("Круглый неряха" мне не попадался.)

[Род имени существительного](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ap5fDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%85%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=Hc207ZnZNY&sig=ACfU3U2OT7AKJyKEwY1lQoOGPxup3FVbcg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV4oXDy5PlAhXP-ioKHYxuApU4ChDoATACegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%85%D0%B0&f=false)